# mail spam server filter gateway

Tags: postfix-mta, spamassassin

I have an exchange 2010 multi-tenant email server that has email addresses of many domains. I want to setup a spam filter for my mail server I have been looking on the internet but cant figure out the best solution to implement. Spamassasin with Postfix. Spamassasin i understand does not delete any emails but just marks the email. Postfix can be used as a MTA to forward email to the mail server. but postfix does not store any emails. how can i implement a solution whereby i have a server that stores all ham and spam emails but only forwards the ham emails to my mail server so i can check the spam server if there is any false positives. If you could please just give pointers in the right direction

thanks

Rehan Miah

Answer (score 0):

Just set up spamassassin to mark all of the likely spam emails (set the score pretty high on day 1) and then set a Transport Rule on Exchange that intercepts the spams based on the string added to the subject field, and then does something with them (delete them, drop them in a spam trap mailbox, whatever).

Have the spamassassin box be the MX for the domains and then forward to the Exchange server (have the Exchange consider it a trusted sender) but make sure to lock spamassassin down to only allow mails sent to domains you care about.

If you have multiple domains, set up a test domain to try the spamassassin setup on before getting serious with clients' domains.